# Windows Server 2008 - Cannot set paging file on a different drive

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, paging

I have a VM running Windows Server 2008 R2 and I can't seem to get the paging file configuration to take. I created a 30 GB virtual disk on the host machine to use as a paging file drive, and named it the P drive in the VM.

The first thing I tried was to set the C drive paging file to none, and setting the P drive paging file to "System managed." After rebooting, I got an error that said "Windows created a temporary paging file on your computer because of a problem that occurred with your paging file configuration when you started your computer. The total paging file size for all disk drives may be somewhat larger than the size you specified." The total RAM is 28.0 GB, so I re-created the virtual disk and made it 50 GB, then tried again. Same error.

After a bit of research, I found that windows needs a small page file on the OS drive for boot dumps. So I changed the settings so that there is an 800 MB paging file on the C drive, and a 50 GB paging file on the P drive. Now when I boot, I don't receive an error, but the total paging file size for all drives only shows 800 MB, and the P drive is completely empty, aside from the hidden recycle bin folder and the system volume information.

The virtual disk is configured as a SCSI drive and the P drive is formatted as NTFS.

Thanks in advance for your help.
-Joel

Comment: What is your working set size?

Comment: @JimB, I'm not sure what the working set is exactly, but my RAM is currently using 20 GB. What information would be helpful to know?

Answer (score 0):

Create a new VMDK hard drive (50GB) and set the page file to use the new drive.